# generate objects from wcf service reference with T4

Tags: c#, wcf, t4, dto, service-reference

I am working with integrating an MVC4 application with WCF services. At present, I generate a service reference from the WCF services endpoint using svcutil.

I have a number of services eg. a BooksServiceReference and CarsServiceReference. An issue I have is that both service references share the same entities but my code treats them differently as they have different namespaces. For example, both references have a Price entity which is the same, only a different namespace.

What I want to do but unsure in doing is the follows. Use T4 mapping to take each class in the service reference file and generate a DTO object for it. So at this point, I have my own DTO object for all classes in the service reference.

Next step, exclude the common entities via a T4 configuration file that are common to both service references. I believe this will be manual and I am fine with this.

For the common entities to, I create a separate T4 configuration file which generates these in to one DTO file.

I have only done some brief work with T4 generation so would appreciate any assistance with the above?

Comment: This sounds like a huge hassle -- are you aware that you can re-use objects on client and server if you define the DataContract classes in a shared library project?

Comment: Yes but sharing libraries can be a pain from past experience.

Comment: A simpler way, if you're OK with the Visual Studio service reference approach, is to take advantage of [this Visual Studio service reference generation feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653(v=VS.100).aspx). I prefer sharing service contract only assemblies as dbaseman suggests but the service reference approach is workable.